# How to concatenate col and row headers in excel VBA based on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate col and row headers based on the cell value. Sample data is added as below.

Sample data:
[image: Sample data]

Wherever cell value is '1' then row and col headers needs to be concatenated and written into a new worksheet. Sample result is as below. I am a beginner and still trying to learn so any help I can get is greatly appreciated.

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please post what you came up with first? We would much rather help you achieve the solution yourself than give it to you straight up on a silver platter solving the excercise for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Concatenate Row and Column Labels

- This is a beginner-intermediate code and surely can be written more efficiently.
- Adjust (play with) the values in the constants section.
- It is assumed that the 'row labels column' and the 'column labels row' (headers) don't contain empty cells (because `xlDown`, `xlToRight` would fail).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub concatHeaders()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    Const sCriteria As Long = 1
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    Const dHeader As String = "Result"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Range
    With wb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst)
        Dim fRow As Long: fRow = .Row
        Dim lRow As Long: lRow = .End(xlDown).Row
        Dim fCol As Long: fCol = .Column
        Dim lCol As Long: lCol = .End(xlToRight).Column
        Set srg = .Resize(lRow - fRow + 1, lCol - fCol + 1)
        'Debug.Print srg.Address
    End With

    ' Destination
    Dim dCell  As Range: Set dCell = wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst)
    dCell.Value = dHeader ' write header
    
    ' Write
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = fRow + 1 To lRow
        For c = fCol + 1 To lCol
            If srg(r, c).Value = sCriteria Then
                Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1) ' next row
                dCell.Value = srg(r, 1).Value & srg(1, c).Value ' write
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go with formula then use `FILTERXML()` with `TEXTJOIN()`.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,IF(B2:E5=1,A2:A5&B1:E1,""))&"</s></t>","//s")
```

[image]